# Location of context menu strip

Tags: vb.net

I have a context menu strip on my form which is displayed on right click on the datagridview.
Problem is the menu is displayed on the upper right corner while I want to show it on the location where mouse is clicked.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have associated the menu to the Datagridview using the ContextMenuStrip  property of the DataGridView?

Comment: @Steve Do it, its a good answer

Answer (score 3):

A ContextMenuStrip could be automatically shown by a DataGridView at the location of the MouseDown click event.

For this to happen it is necessary to associate the property ContextMenuStrip to the actual instance of your menu strip. You could do this either by code or directly in the designer

```
 DataGridView1.ContextMenuStrip = ctxMenu;
```